# Operações aritmética onde alguns dados do DataFrame não são int no Python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Estou trabalhando com alguns dados do IBGE e me encontro com duas planilhas que preciso tirar a porcentagem delas.

A formula para isso é bem simples, ou seja:

> porcentagem = (dividendo / divisor) * 100

Seguindo, tenho, a exemplo, os dois DataFrame:

```
data1 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
         'prod_1': [576, 456, 789, 963]}
divisor = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
         'prod_2': [123, '-', 231, '-']}
dividendo = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Quando aplico a formula para obter as porcentagens:

```
quociente = ( dividendo['prod_2'] / divisor['prod_1'] ) * 100
```

Eu tenho o seguinte erro, que já é esperado:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Contudo, o problema está em, como eu contorno isso para obter as porcentagens e ignorar os espaços que contem `'-'`?

Usar `for` e `if` está fora de cogitação por ser mais ou menos 70 tabelas com 500 linhas. Além de que, dizem que não é uma boa prática de programação para o Pandas/Python.

No final de tudo, precisarei fazer um merge de todas essas planilhas e criar uma com as 70 tabelas que eu quero, porém, estou perdido em não conseguir fazer a porcentagem de forma eficiente.

Comment: Qual o resultado que espera receber de `'-' / 456`?

Comment: Bom, de acordo com o IBGE, sempre que vem ```'-'``` ou ```'X'```, indica que não houve recolhimento suficiente de dados, ou que não houve produção alguma. No caso, caso tenha ```'-'```, o certo seria ter o mesmo ```'-'```, ou algum texto que indique isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução seria gerar duas [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html) uma para `prod_1` e outra para `prod_2` e as converter coercitivamente para um formato numérico através do método [`pandas.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) como parâmetro `errors` ajustado com `coerce` o que força a valores inválidos serem convertido para `NAN` e valores válidos para `numpy.float64`.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
  'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
  'prod_1': [576, 456, 789, 963]
}

data2 = {
  'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
  'prod_2': [123, '-', 231, '-']
}

dividendo = pd.Series(data2['prod_2'])
divisor = pd.Series(data1['prod_1'])

dividendo = pd.to_numeric(dividendo,errors = 'coerce')
divisor = pd.to_numeric(divisor,errors = 'coerce')

print(dividendo / divisor * 100)
```

Resultando:

```
0    21.354167
1          NaN
2    29.277567
3          NaN
dtype: float64
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/LightgreenYellowishPcboard

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar o for nunca está fora de cogitação! O que o seu código faz é o mesmo que um `for`, você só não escreve o for. O melhor jeito é usar o for:

```py
data1 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
         'prod_1': [576, 456, 789, 963]}
divisor = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Curitiba', 'Salvador'],
         'prod_2': [123, '-', 231, '-']}
dividendo = pd.DataFrame(data2)

quociente = []

for i in range(len(dividendo['prod_2'])):
    try:
        quociente.append(dividendo['prod_2'][i] / divisor['prod_1'][i] * 100)
    except:
        quociente.append(0)
```

Mas o que eu mais recomendaria seria você limpar o dataframe primeiro.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, gostei muito das soluções propostas. Testei cada uma delas e vi que funcionavam para aquilo que eu queria fazer.

Mas o usuário `Augusto Vasques` e `Arthur Bacci` me derão uma ideia, dessa forma, mudei um pouco a abordagem consegui o resultado desejado da seguinte forma:

```
data1 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Salvador'],
         'prod_1': [576, 456, 963]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'local': ['São Paulo', 'Curitiba'],
         'prod_2': [123, 231]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

nova = df1.merge(df2.set_index('local'), on='local')
```

Obtendo o seguinte resultado:

```
        local           prod_1  prod_2
0       São Paulo       576.0   123.0
1       Rio de Janeiro  456.0   NaN
2       Salvador        963.0   NaN
3       Curitiba        NaN     231.0
```

Com os resultados `NaN` eu coloquei um `.fillna('-')` ou `.fillna('X')` que preenchirá eles com aquilo que será o mais correto de acordo com a situação.

Do mais, agradeço a todos que colaboraram com uma resposta ou questionamento. Fica aí a solução que acabei usando.